# Having more than 2B docs in an Elasticsearch index

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an elasticsearch cluster with one index. At some point I started getting the following error when inserting new documents:

> number of documents in the index cannot exceed 2147483519

After searching online I saw that splitting the index into several primary shards should help. I split the index into a new index with 3 shards (instead of the previous 1) but I'm still getting the error writing to the newly split index.
Did I misunderstand this? Is there anything I can do to be able to continue adding more documents to the index?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In theory, increasing the number of primary shards should have helped; can you confirm you're not trying to write into the same exhausted shard (e.g., you have some routing or allocation strategy in place, or some join types)?

Anyhow, I would recommend you split your index into multiple indices rather than increasing the number of shards. It depends anyhow on your specific use case. E.g.,

- if you're dealing with append-only data, DEFINITELY go for a rolling index approach
- If you're not dealing with append-only data, try to split the index across one particular dimension, e.g., based on a field value.

Comment: Thanks, @glenacota!
I'm new to elasticsearch so maybe I did something wrong. Here's the config of the new index: https://pastebin.com/0HdpAB3h
I will definitely check the rolling index approach, thanks!

Comment: there you go: you have the `index.routing_partition_size: 1`, that will route ingestion of all docs into the same shard :) https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-routing-field.html#routing-index-partition - although you could remove it, I still stand by my recommendation of considering a multi-index approach :)

Comment: Thanks! I'll dig into the multi-index approach :)